# Javascript dynamic table doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to add row when user click "Add" button, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```js
function Add() {
     var table1 = document.getElementById("insertTable");
     var tr = document.createElement("tr");
     tr.setAttribute("bgColor", "#FFFFCC");
     tr.setAttribute("height", "30");

    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.setAttribute("width", "100");
    td1.innerText = document.all.txtHome.value;
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.setAttribute("width", "200");
    td2.innerText = document.all.txtAway.value;

    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    if (table1.firstChild.lastChild.childNodes.length == 1)
        table1.firstChild.removeChild(table1.firstChild.lastChild);
    //delete "No Text" row

    table1.firstChild.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="300" id="insertTable">
<tr>
    <th width="100">City:</th>
    <th width="200">Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">No Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
City:<input type="text" size="10" name="txtHome" />
Country:<input type="text" size="10" name="txtAway" />
<button onclick="Add();">Add</button>
```

Comment: Avoid using `document.all` as it is deprecated in various browsers. Instead use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` to ensure compatibility.

Comment: I am beginner of web develop, so i didn't know that. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this works.

Don't forget that a table always has a `<tbody>` even if not defined explicitly.
Given that the `<tr>` elements are all children of the tbody, better to define that explicitly and give it the "insertTable" id.

You can then append directly to that without all the confusing firstChild/lastChild stuff.

Also, give an id to the "No text" placeholder row so it's easier to delete.

```js
function Add() {
    var table1 = document.getElementById("insertTable");
    if(table1) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.setAttribute("bgColor", "#FFFFCC");
        tr.setAttribute("height", "30");

        var td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.setAttribute("width", "100");
        td1.innerText = document.all.txtHome.value;
        var td2 = document.createElement("td");
        td2.setAttribute("width", "200");
        td2.innerText = document.all.txtAway.value;

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);

        //delete "No Text" row
        var noText = document.getElementById("noText");
        if(noText) table1.removeChild(noText);

        table1.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="300">
    <tbody id="insertTable">
        <tr>
            <th width="100">City:</th>
            <th width="200">Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="noText">
            <td align="center" colspan="2">No Text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
City:<input type="text" size="10" name="txtHome" />
Country:<input type="text" size="10" name="txtAway" />
<button onclick="Add();">Add</button>
```

Comment: The code snippet in my answer works, yes? If you need more help you're going to have to give a bit more detail than "it still doesn't work!"